# How to embed my Machine-learning R code in a website

Tags: javascript, r

I need to run my R-code through a website, with the user giving feature values from the website itself, which I have to use as new data for prediction in the R-code. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a form on the website which performs an HTML post to a REST api on your web server which will write the information to a database such as MySql, Postgres, MongoDB, or any other database of your choice. Then use a DBMS database management system (DBMS) such as MySQL Workbench, pgAdmin, or Robomongo to query the database and put the data into a csv file, and run your R-code on it. Then use the parameters from your machine-learning model on your server to serve content.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose any R code as a REST API using packages such as plumber, OpenCPU or RestServ. Such an API can then be integrated into the website using Jacascript.